# Hibernate Join not by Primary Key

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

(Aware that this is not the first time question being asked, but I tried all of the suggested solutions and it did no good.)

So, I have a Parent entity and a Child entity with a OneToOne mapping - the issue is that the join isn't (and shouldn't) being done by the primary key columns, but by some other id column (a nullable natural id).

I have 4 relevant entities here:

```
class EntityId implements Serializable {
    int storeId;
    long uniqueId;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(EntityId.class)
@Immutable
@Table(name = "parent")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING,
    name = "disc_type"
)
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "store_id")
    private int storeId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "unique_id")
    private long uniqueId;

    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Extended")
public class ExtendedParent extends Parent {
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="parent")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private ExtendedChild child;

    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}

@Immutable
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractChild {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "extended_child")
public class ExtendedChild extends AbstractChild {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private ExtendedParent parent;
}
```

Unfortunately, whenever I try to start the application it fails with "Failed to load Application Context" with the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>       at org.hibernate.sql.ANSIJoinFragment.addJoin(ANSIJoinFragment.java:81)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.addJoins(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:281)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.renderEntityJoin(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:184)

The problem is that it simply ignored the referencedColumnName and attempts to join via the primary key - visible when we investigate it further (breakpoint in the exception row - this is the root cause):

[image]

The right-hand side of the join in the left join (ignore the names of the columns) includes that are defined as the @Id of the Parent, instead of the "id" column defined in the ExtendedParent entity, as defined in the @JoinColumn in the ExtendedChild entity.

NOTE: I also tried setting the id column as a natural identifier with the @NaturalId annotation (moving it into the root entity Parent + adding the annotation there) but it made no difference - same error.

Ideas?